# Regex.test(value) returns true when logged but false within an if statement

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, if-statement, textfield

I'm noticing something weird with my code. I have a regex to check UK postcodes, it uses capture groups and works fine unless within an if statement. The code to test is within a validator class which is passed an HTML node list with all fields from a form.

For example, when I use it within the `pattern` tag on the HTML input field it acts as you would expect. As it does when I `console.log(regex.test(field.value))`. However, when I put it into an if statement it seems to fail every time.

The regex is as follows:

```
/\b([a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]?){1}( |-)?([0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}){1}\b/
```

The input field is as follows:

```
<input required pattern="\b([a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]?){1}( |-)?([0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}){1}\b" inputmode="text" class="form-field" type="text" name="postcode" id="contactPostcode" placeholder="Postcode eg NW2 8BZ" />
```

The code to test it is as follows:

```
validate(fields)

// ... omitted ... //

let errors = [];

const postcodeRegex = /\b([a-zA-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]?){1}( |-)?([0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{1,2}){1}\b/;

postcodeRegex.lastIndex = 0;

for (let field of fields) {

    if(field.name === 'postcode') {
        console.log(postcodeRegex.test(field.value))
        if(!postcodeRegex.test(field.value)) {
            errors.push({
                field: field.getAttribute('name'),
                error: 'Illegal character detected'
            });
            continue;
        }
    }

}
```

The console.log check returns true however the if statement check returns false every time and I don't understand why the two identical checks would output different results, does anyone have any advice? I am guessing something is going over my head here.

Thanks

Edit for clarification: The console log's `true` but the if statement is *still* being executed

Comment: `!true === false` if the console logs `true` the code in the `if` statement will not be executed.

Comment: This is the problem, the if statement is executed still

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case the problem is what @AthanasiosKataras has mentioned.

Comment: @Titus Yeah it still seems to fail within the if statement when there isn't any other use of the regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per documentation 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

> As with exec() (or in combination with it), test() called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous

So this is why the second time you get false.

Try this:

```
var res = postcodeRegex.test(field.value);
console.log(res)
        if(!res) {
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is related to the `regex.lastIndex = 0` situation, right? The weirder thing is, even when I remove the console log the test returns false within the if statement. So, with just the log it returns true but with just the if statement it returns false.

Comment: I think this is the case only when the regex is set to be global (the `g` flag) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Using_test_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag

Comment: @titus Yeah that was my take of it and this isn't using the `g` flag. I have tried to negate/test by removing the log altogether and by inserting `regex.lastIndex = 0` between the log and the if statement. However, same result -- fails within the if statement when it should pass.

Comment: Nice one, that's done it. Any idea why this is needed?