# Why can TS narrow type when return is present but not when return is not?

Tags: typescript

I have this script:

```
type Input = string
function util(input: Input) {
    return input
}

function main(input: Input | null) {
    const isNull = input === null
    if (isNull) {
        return 'empty string'
    }    
    input = util(input) //error
}
```

The error is: `Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

However, it doesn't happen if:

- The last line is `return util(input)`, or
- The condition line is shorten to `if (input === null)`

Why is that?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsKBeKBnYAnAlnAcwCgAzROAY2FwHs4plcAbACnyWAC5YFkBKKAG8iUUVGwRgibPXbIiAXyKlyVWvQC2AQ3xteXHhygAfKHERMmA4WKgU6WKLgwA5C0zRP9aVOnOWRMVwSKDZXd2tA0QB6aKcQvSNfPwihKNtxSWl6AHIIDTBQTBx8Ahz0hVt0uRR0RlYavkUgA)

---

The reason I don't check the value at the condition clause because I want to check not only if it's null, but also to test whether it matches an regex string. And because [regex.test(value) returns true when logged but false within an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59694184/3416774), I want to combine them all in a variable, then checking that variable. That's more convenient.

```
    const isNullOrEmpty = input === null || /^\\s+$/.test(input)
    if (isNullOrEmpty)
```

is better to manage than:

```
    const isEmpty = /^\\s+$/.test(input)
    if (input === null || isEmpty)
```

Comment: `isNull` is just a plain `boolean`, so `if (isNull)` gives the compiler no type information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem counterintuitive - and it is in my opinion - but Typescript can't use an intermediate variable to infer the type of the values that were used to give that variable its value.

You need to either use `if (input === null)` or write and use a type predicate `isNull`.

EDIT:

Here is what it would look like using a type predicate:

```js
const isNull = (value: any): value is null => {
    return value === null;
};

const doSomething = (value: string | null) => {
    if (isNull(value)) {
        return 'foo';
    }

    return value.charAt(0); // valid; at that point, TypeScript compiler knows that value is not null - hence it is a string
};
```

I'm not sure it is adding anything to simply writing `if (value === null)`, though.

Comment: How would you use type predicate? Also, do you know what happens in `return util(input)`?

Comment: I augmented my answer to add a type predicate sample.

Comment: the reason I don't check the value at the condition clause because I want to check not only if it's null, but also to test whether it matches an regex string. And because [regex.test(value) returns true when logged but false within an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59694184/3416774), I want to combine them all in a variable, then checking that variable. That's more convenient.